# Can 痛み also refer to emotional pain?

Tags: english-to-japanese, japanese-to-english

Does 痛み only refer to physical pain or can it also mean emotional pain?
Could I use it to say something like

"What's wrong?"

> どうしたんですか？

"I failed the exam. I'm embarrassed and scared."

> 試験に失敗したんです。恥ずかしくて怖いんです。

"I feel your pain."

> あなたの痛みを分かるんです。

Comment: Jisho shows 誠実さの痛みを和らげる - "Relieves the pains of being sincere", so I feel like it's possible, but it's true that the majority of the time it's about physical pain. Maybe another word is preferred, 苦しみ perhaps?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61546/5010

Comment: This is not related to your doubt but your use of ん in the last sentence is not proper.

Comment: Should it have been 分かったんです? @aguijonazo

Comment: @SpikedHelmet "あなたの痛み、分かります" or something like that. You don't need ん.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, yes, 痛み includes non-physical pain.

Typically 心が痛む (or 胸が痛い) means something like *My conscience bothers me* and not any kind of cardiac problems.

---

But, in the particular example you give, 痛み is unlikely to be used in the first place. Possible translations would be:

- そのつらさ(は)わかります
- お気持ち( or 心中)お察しします

(Note that these are overly polite when you are talking to friends)